# Is there in android studio any possibility to send a broadcast from one app to another by using two different emulators which are simultaneously open?

Tags: android

i have 2 android studio projects
-one to send broadcast:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.example.broadcast");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

}

-other one to receive:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MyReceiver myReceiver = new MyReceiver();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.broadcast");
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}
```

}

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("test", "test");
        Toast.makeText(context, "HALLO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

The whole thing works, if i start both apps in one emulator,
but since i start them separately in two emulators, it doesnt work.

how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

No way to send the broadcast to different devices. If you want to do this maybe you can research FCM (Firebase Cloud Message).

Answer (score 0):

You can use peer to peer (p2p) to connect your devices as long as it's on the same network.

[See p2p docs here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct)